# How to start again Quartz jobs that are created dynamically after a server shutdown

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, cron, quartz-scheduler

I'm using spring mvc 4.2.5.RELEASE and quartz 2.2.1 quartz-jobs 2.2.1

I have a user interface when the user inputs the name and the cron expression of a quartz job, and then I create the job like this

```
SchedulerFactory schedFact = new org.quartz.impl.StdSchedulerFactory();

schedFact.getScheduler().getContext().put("externalInstanceEstatus", myObject);
Scheduler sched = schedFact.getScheduler();
sched.start();

JobDetail job = null;
job = newJob(MyTask.class)
.withIdentity((String) String.valueOf(myUniqueId), "group1")
.build();

Trigger triggerCron = TriggerBuilder
.newTrigger()
.withIdentity(String.valueOf(myUniqueId), "group1")
.withSchedule(
    CronScheduleBuilder.cronSchedule(myObject.getExpresionCron()))
.build();

sched.scheduleJob(job, triggerCron);
```

Everytime that the user goes that interface he can create a job this works fine 
but when I turn off the server all of my Jobs are lost. I solved this by saving the Job name and cron expression in a database and I created a method that fetch all the records from that table and I re-create the Jobs like this

```
public void reCreateJobs() {

        ArrayList<MyJob> listOfJobs = searchAllJobsInDB();

        SchedulerFactory schedFact = new org.quartz.impl.StdSchedulerFactory();
        Scheduler sched = schedFact.getScheduler();

        //I loop the lsit and I delete all the jobs in the scheduler just in case
        for (MyJob myJob : listOfJobs) {
            for (String group : sched.getJobGroupNames()) {
                for (JobKey jobKey : sched.getJobKeys((GroupMatcher<JobKey>) groupEquals(group))) {
                    if (jobKey.getName().equals(String.valueOf(myJob.getIdMyJob()))) {
                        sched.deleteJob(jobKey);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        sched.start();

        //THIS IS WHERE I CREATE ALL THE JOBS AGAIN
        for (MyJob myJob : listOfJobs) {

            JobDetail job = newJob(TareaImprimir.class)
                    .withIdentity((String) String.valueOf(myJob.getIdMyJob()), "group1")
                    .build();

            JobDetail job = null;

            Trigger triggerCron = TriggerBuilder
                    .newTrigger()
                    .withIdentity(String.valueOf(myJob.getIdMyJob()), "group1")
                    .withSchedule(
                            CronScheduleBuilder.cronSchedule(myJob.getExpresionCron()))
                    .build();

            sched.scheduleJob(job, triggerCron);
        }
    }
```

This also works fine I can create the Jobs again and they run fine,

My problem is that I need to pass a value to the Task Class and I don't know how to pass it, I know how to pass it when I create the job for the first time like this

```
schedFact.getScheduler().getContext().put("externalInstance", myObject);
```

and then I get it in my task Class like this

```
 SchedulerContext schedulerContext = null;
    try {
        schedulerContext = context.getScheduler().getContext();

    } catch (SchedulerException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    MyObject externalInstance
            = (MyObject) schedulerContext.get("externalInstance");
```

My Problem is that I don't know how to do this when I'm recreating the Jobs in my method `reCreateJobs()` where I get them from the DataBase

How can I set that externalInstance inside my method `reCreateJobs()` for every Job or How can I pass that value to the MyTask class inside that loop

this is my Task Class

```
public class MyTask implements Job {

@Autowired
SomeDAO someDAO;

public void execute(JobExecutionContext context)
        throws JobExecutionException {

    SpringBeanAutowiringSupport.processInjectionBasedOnCurrentContext(this);

    SchedulerContext schedulerContext = null;
    try {
        schedulerContext = context.getScheduler().getContext();
    } catch (SchedulerException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(MyTask.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    MyObject externalInstance
            = (MyObject) schedulerContext.get("externalInstance");

    someDAO.doSomething(externalInstance.getSomething());
}
```

}

Answer (score 3):

*Since i cant comment, adding it as an answer*

Any reason why you are you not using [JDBC-JobStoreTX](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.x/configuration/ConfigJobStoreTX.html)

> JDBCJobStore is used to store scheduling information (job, triggers and calendars) within a relational database. There are actually two seperate JDBCJobStore classes that you can select between, depending on the transactional behaviour you need.
>
> JobStoreTX manages all transactions itself by calling commit() (or rollback()) on the database connection after every action (such as the addition of a job). JDBCJobStore is appropriate if you are using Quartz in a stand-alone application, or within a servlet container if the application is not using JTA transactions.

That way you can persist the data you want to [JobDataMap](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/api/2.2.1/org/quartz/JobDataMap.html)

> Holds state information for Job instances.
>
> JobDataMap instances are stored once when the Job is added to a scheduler. They are also re-persisted after every execution of jobs annotated with @PersistJobDataAfterExecution.
>
> JobDataMap instances can also be stored with a Trigger. This can be useful in the case where you have a Job that is stored in the scheduler for regular/repeated use by multiple Triggers, yet with each independent triggering, you want to supply the Job with different data inputs.
>
> The JobExecutionContext passed to a Job at execution time also contains a convenience JobDataMap that is the result of merging the contents of the trigger's JobDataMap (if any) over the Job's JobDataMap (if any).