# Scheduling after Job object in Quatz

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler

I implement a class like

```
public class GreetingJob implements Job{

     private Greeting salut;

     public GreetingJob(Greeting salut){
          this.salut = salut;
     }

     @Override
     public void execute(JobExecutionContext context) throws JobExecutionException {
           System.out.println(salut);       
     }

  }
```

with class model

```
public class Greeting {

    private String name;
    private String greeting;

    public Greeting(String name, String greeting) {
        this.name = name;
        this.greeting = greeting;
    }

    public String getName() {
         return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
         this.name = name;
    }

    public String getGreeting() {
         return greeting;
    }

    public void setGreeting(String greeting) {
         this.greeting = greeting;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
         return "Salut [name=" + name + ", greeting=" + greeting + "]";
    }
}
```

How can be doing scheduling after an object of a type that is derived like that in quartz?

Comment: why are you calling `super();` when your class doesn't extend nothing?

Comment: It that way is generated, I deleted now.  But this is not related to the problem

Comment: Do you have custom greeting for each new job you create? If so you can use JobDataMap to persist this info so when the job is scheduled you wil have access to it. take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/41656968/2469484 If you are trying to achieve something else please add more info to your question

Comment: @Srinivas That can be a possible solution.